# How to AOT compile a single clojure file using clj tool? (without deps.edn file)

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have the following file:

*hello/core.clj*:

```
(ns hello.core)

(println "Hello")
```

Is it possible to AOT compile this file to classfiles using a `clj` tool without using any "project"-like setup? I've tried something like this:

```
$ clj -e '(compile "hello/core")'
```

but am getting an error about unability to locate `hello/core.clj` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `clj`'s default expectation is for source files to be under `src` directory ([from the guide](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli#_writing_a_program)):

> By default, the `clj` tool will look for source files in the `src` directory, so create the `src` directory and declare your program at `src/hello.clj`

And for `compile` to work, `*compile-path*` (defaults to `"classes"`) must also exist:

```
$ mkdir classes
$ tree
.
├── classes
└── src
    └── hello
        └── core.clj

$ test clj -e "(compile 'hello.core)"
Hello
hello.core
```

Then your class files should be in `classes` directory.